# How to inject code from one thread to another in Clojure (for live OpenGL editing in the REPL)?

Tags: clojure, lwjgl

How to inject code from one thread to another in Clojure?

I'm using Clojure with LWJGL and have implemented a game loop. I want to edit it interactively using the REPL. Consequently I have moved the loop and all OpenGL calls to a separate thread (using Java Runnables). I have has some success in changing the loop from the outside by: A. using atoms, accessible to both threads, and changing them from the REPL thread e.g. (:color @globals) and B. storing Clojure code as an atom `(:code @globals)`, changing it from the REPL, and accessing it in the thread loop like so: `(eval (:code @globals))`.

But Clojure's symbols are all bound to one thread. I can send a message to add 2 and two `(+ 2 2)`, but it doesn't get much further than that.

As a LISP, Clojure has the code as data advantage. I want to leverage this to use my REPL thread to modify my graphics thread, but need to get around the symbol binding thing - how?

My loop:

```
(while (not (GLFW/glfwWindowShouldClose window))  
    (eval (:code @globals))  
    (GL11/glClearColor (get (:color @globals) 0) (get (:color @globals) 1)  
             (get (:color @globals) 2) (get (:color @globals) 3) )  
     ......  
 )
```

Comment: I'm going to be developing a game in Clojure with LWJGL. My plan is to use Stuart Sierra's [reloaded workflow](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2013/06/04/clojure-workflow-reloaded), combined with the [Component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component), [Suspendable](https://github.com/weavejester/suspendable), and [`reloaded.repl`](https://github.com/weavejester/reloaded.repl) libraries. This has worked fairly well for me [before](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/126376/82369) (and I've since found solutions to the problems I mentioned); you might want to look into that workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your function as a value to the shared atom. There is no need to pass the raw Clojure code as data and eval it - you can just pass the function value:

```
(def my-function (atom (fn [])))

(.start
  (Thread.
    (fn []
      (while true
        (@my-function)
        (Thread/sleep 1000)))))

(reset! my-function
  (fn [] (println "A")))

;; wait a few seconds    
;; prints 'A's with one second interval


(reset! my-function
  (fn [] (println "B")))

;; prints 'B's with one second interval
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - I didn't really think of passing the function. My concern is that this way still means I cannot access any vars or even atoms inside the function body. There is a lot of LWJGL and vertex buffer etc. setup code  - and vars - that precede the loop and I would need to be able to refer to it inside the function. Given the thread local bindings of Clojure I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: You can put each piece of the data into atoms and it will be available across the threads.